# Use a saved vector from SparkR to R

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have saved a long vector from sparkR. I want to save it and use this vector in R.
The vector is u=c(1,2,3,5,6,9,...) and I want to use this vector as entries in a dataset:
data[u,]
How can this be done?

Comment: What are the types of u and dataset? Are they a vector (or an RDD) and a data.frame (or a DataFrame)?

Comment: The data is from a csv-file. In R it's a dataframe and in sparkR its a DataFrame. 'u' is a vector containing integers.

Answer (score 0):

SparkR has no `row.names`, so it's only possible in R, not in SparkR.

Note: The question was answered by @WannesRosiers's comment.